# docker-compose up giving error UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: docker, containers, docker-compose

I am running my nodejs and blockchain code . And I made a Docker Container with dockerfile and docker compose but i am getting error while running the docker-compose up.

This is the traceback on console :

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 121, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 938, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 430, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 317, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 918, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 238, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 285, in _set_auth_headers
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 97, in resolve_authconfig
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 125, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 25, in get
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 57, in _execute
  File "subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

and my docker-compose.yml is :

```js
version: '2'
services:
  node-app:
    build: app
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./app/src:/myapp/src
    depends_on:
      - ethernet_server
    environment:
      - ETHEREUM_CLIENT_IP=http://192.168.178.22
      - ETHEREUM_CLIENT_PORT=8545

  ethernet_server:
    build: testrpc
```

I don't know what went wrong.can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: Does your username or password contain a non-ASCII character?

Comment: no, it has only ASCII characters

Comment: Did you copy&pasted your line 6? Try to delete the whole line (and line breaks)  and re-type it in manually.

Comment: What is the output of `docker-compose config` in the current directory?

Answer (score 5):

Paste the below mentioned lines in your docker file. And it will fix the unicode error.

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install --reinstall -y locales
# uncomment chosen locale to enable it's generation
RUN sed -i 's/# pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8/pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen
# generate chosen locale
RUN locale-gen pl_PL.UTF-8
# set system-wide locale settings 
ENV LANG pl_PL.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE pl_PL
ENV LC_ALL pl_PL.UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar error when running `gdb` inside a container. Uncommenting the `en_US.UTF-8` line in `/etc/locale.gen`, and running `locale-gen` afterwards has fixed the problem. Note though that I already had `en_US.UTF-8` in my `LANG` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try building the containers directly with docker:

`docker build app`

`docker build testrpc`

then run your `docker-compose` again.

I was encountering a similar report from docker-compose of `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0` and found that using docker to rebuild my containers resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while saving `docker` commands i had saved it as a `.odt` file initially and then changed the file extension in `finder` app to `.yml` manually, resulted in above issue.

Used VS code *(you can use any other tool or simply select `all files` as format type while saving)*  to save the file with `.yml` extension and then tried executing `docker-compose` again worked for me.